# Android Gallery Starting Selection Drawable

Tags: android, gallery, selection, drawable

I have a Gallery that I've set up with [this](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/drawable/gallery_item_background.xml;h=c7eb7ea8b93c5022fe6710e87a552ca0fa47604f;hb=HEAD) type of thing.  Works great, except on initial load.  The initial gallery item isn't "selected" according to the drawable.  Sliding the gallery back and forth makes it work fine and going back to the first has it selected correctly.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [this](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/drawable/gallery_item_background.xml;h=c7eb7ea8b93c5022fe6710e87a552ca0fa47604f;hb=HEAD#l17) as a guide.  I didn't get exactly what I wanted, but this was useful.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "selected"?  `Gallery` only draws a "selector" indicator if the view is focused, which usually only happens when you're using non-touch input (e.g., arrow keys, jogball, etc).  If you touch/swipe to move around in it, you enter "touch mode", which usually does *not* draw a "selector".  The same is true of `ListView`.  [Read this](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/touch-mode.html) for more information on what Touch Mode is, and why it's important to understand the difference.

Comment: By selected I mean the active item.  The one in the center.  Id like that one to be a different color/drawable than the others that are not selected/focused.